# Как взять текст из QComboBox

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты, qcombobox

У меня возникла проблема с получением текста из `comboBox`. 
Вот мой код, мне надо выводить в консоль текст из `comboBox`.

```
from pydoc import text
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(639, 451)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 380, 121, 71))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 360, 121, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 430, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 430, 71, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 410, 71, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 410, 47, 13))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        index = self.comboBox.findText

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
     
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Выберете версию"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "1.16.5"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "1.14.1"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "1.12.2"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "1.8.9"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите ник"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "текущий ник: "))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "NULL"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Данный  код был преобразован из **.ui** файла *Qt Designer*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> void QComboBox::[**currentTextChanged**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentTextChanged)(const QString &text)
>
> Этот сигнал отправляется всякий раз, когда изменяется `currentText`. 
> Новое значение передается как текст.

---

НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный *Qt Designer*, НИКОГДА. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

```
# ??? from pydoc import text
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(639, 451)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 380, 121, 71))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 360, 121, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 430, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 430, 71, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 410, 71, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 410, 47, 13))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
# ???        index = self.comboBox.findText

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
     
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Выберете версию"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "1.16.5"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "1.14.1"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "1.12.2"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "1.8.9"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите ник"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "текущий ник: "))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "NULL"))


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
    
        self.comboBox.currentTextChanged.connect(self.current_text_changed)

    def current_text_changed(self, text):
        print(f'Изменяется currentText, новое значение: {text}')
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

#    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
#    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
#    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
#    MainWindow.show()

    w = MainWindow()                                                      # +++
    w.show()                                                              # +++
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: СПАСИБО огромное

Comment: @FIFIFiSKA, пожалуйста. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Извините, а не подскажите как выводить значение LineEdit я просто только начал пользоваться PyQt5

Comment: @FIFIFiSKA https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#text-prop

Comment: @FIFIFiSKA, если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос.